# JS sorting by two values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, indexing

I need sort array with Bustype and index

What I have

```
[
  { BusType: "SATA", index: 1, Id: "SATA.1" },
  { BusType: "SATA", index: 10, Id: "SATA.10" },
  { BusType: "IDE", index: 1, Id: "IDE.1" },
  { BusType: "IDE", index: 2, Id: "IDE.2" },
  { BusType: "IDE", index: 10, Id: "IDE.10" },
]
```

Expected ouput:

```
[
  { BusType: "IDE", index: 1, Id: "IDE.1" },
  { BusType: "IDE", index: 2, Id: "IDE.2" },
  { BusType: "IDE", index: 10, Id: "IDE.10" },
  { BusType: "SATA", index: 1, Id: "SATA.1" },
  { BusType: "SATA", index: 10, Id: "SATA.10" }
]
```

I tried this:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a.Id.localeCompare(b.Id))
```

but got this :

```
[
  { BusType: "IDE", index: 1, Id: "IDE.1" },
  { BusType: "IDE", index: 10, Id: "IDE.10" },
  { BusType: "IDE", index: 2, Id: "IDE.2" },
  { BusType: "SATA", index: 1, Id: "SATA.1" },
  { BusType: "SATA", index: 10, Id: "SATA.10" }
]
```

Sorting like alphabet.. 1 10  100 2 20 3

how to sort in right derection?

Comment: `array.sort((a, b) => <first expression> || <second expression>);` <= you give it two expressions separated by an OR.  In the case that they are both equal, the second expression will evaluate as equality in comparisons is `0` and `falsy`.  So using that pattern you can have two layers of sorting.

Comment: `arr.sort((a, b) => a.BustType.localeCompare(b.BustType) || a.index - b.index);` which sorts by `BustType` and if that returns `0` (meaning they have the same `BusType`) then the `||` kicks in and the `a.index - b.index` is used instead which will sort by `index`

Comment: working fine! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr.sort((a, b) => a.BustType.localeCompare(b.BustType) || a.index - b.index);
```

Which will sort by `BustType` and if that returns `0` (meaning they have the same `BusType`), then the right side of `||` kicks in and `a.index - b.index` is used instead which will sort by `index`. This is called [**short-circuit evaluation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a multi-sort.

You just need to declare some sorters. These are just a way to tell the sorting function about your fields i.e. what type and which direction is to be sorted.

Here is an example sorter:

```js
/**
 * @param {String} name - Object field to be compared
 * @param {String=['string'],'int'} type - Value type
 * @param {String=['asc'],'desc'} dir - Sort direction
 * @param {Function} fn - Optional comparator function
 */
const exampleSorter = {
  name : 'field',
  type : 'string',
  dir  : 'asc'
  fn   : (a, b) => a - b
}
```

Sorters can be:

- A single string field name
- A mixed array of field names or sorter objects

### Demo

```js
const busData = [
  { BusType: "SATA" , index: 1  , Id: "SATA.1"  },
  { BusType: "SATA" , index: 10 , Id: "SATA.10" },
  { BusType: "IDE"  , index: 1  , Id: "IDE.1"   },
  { BusType: "IDE"  , index: 2  , Id: "IDE.2"   },
  { BusType: "IDE"  , index: 10 , Id: "IDE.10"  },
]

const multiSort = (data, sorters) => {
  const defaultSorter = { type: 'string', dir: 'asc' }
  const compare = (a, b, sorter) => {
    let field = sorter.name
    if (b == null || b[field] == null) return -1
    if (a == null || a[field] == null) return 1
    if (sorter.fn) return sorter.fn.call(sorter, a[field], b[field])
    switch (sorter.type) {
      case 'int':     return a[field] - b[field];
      case 'string':
      default:        return a[field].localeCompare(b[field])
    }
  }
  if (typeof sorters === 'string') sorters = [sorters]
  sorters = sorters.map(sorter => typeof sorter === 'string'
      ? { ...defaultSorter, name: sorter }
      : { ...defaultSorter, sorter })
  return data.sort((a, b) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < sorters.length; i++) {
      let sorter = sorters[i], result = compare(a, b, sorter)
      if (result !== 0) return result * (sorter.dir === 'desc' ? -1 : 1)
    }
    return 0
  })
}

console.log(multiSort(busData, [
  { name: 'BusType', fn: (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b) },
  { name: 'index', type: 'int', dir: 'asc' }
]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arr.sort(
  (a,b)=> {
    a.BusType<b.BusType?-1:
    a.BusType>b.BusType?1:
    a.index<b.index?-1:
    a.index>b.index?1:
    0;
  }
);
```

We compare `BusType`, -1 if a's is smaller, 1 if a's is bigger, and if equal:
we compare `index`, -1 if a's is smaller, 1 if a's is bigger, and if equal: 0.

Answer (score -2):

`.sort` was a good choice:

```js
const a = [
  {BusType: "SATA", index: 1, Id: "SATA.1"},
  {BusType: "SATA", index: 10, Id: "SATA.10"},
  {BusType: "IDE", index: 1, Id: "IDE.1"},
  {BusType: "IDE", index: 2, Id: "IDE.2"},
  {BusType: "IDE", index: 10, Id: "IDE.10"},
];
const res = a.slice(); // so we don't change original Array
res.sort((a, b)=>{
  return a.BusType.localeCompare(b.BusType) || +a.index.toString().match(/^[0-9]/)[0] > +b.index.toString().match(/^[0-9]/)[0]
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: What about `index`?

Comment: String equality should normally use the `localeCompare` method.

Comment: I fixed the expression.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to `match` the index from the `Id` string, you can just use the `index` property